# Как определить, что поле фамилии в Telegram пустое?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

У меня есть функция, которая по команде /start собирает имя, фамилию и id пользователя для дальнейшего вывода.

Тут получаем сами данные:

```
global usr
global usr_last
global usr_id
global message_id
usr = message.from_user.first_name
usr_last = message.from_user.last_name
usr_id = message.from_user.id
```

Делаю проверку на пустое поле. В ответ все равно получаю False.

```
print(usr_last == '')

if usr_last == '':
    pass
```

Comment: А `print(usr_last)` делать не пробовали, может там `None`. А вообще-то pytonic-style делать проверку `if not usr_last` - это сработает и при `None`, и при пустой строке.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно забыл про if not...